# How do I know for sure this algebra is impossible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, field-theory

Suppose we have an underdetermined system $y = 2u - v - t$ and $z = \frac{vt}{u^2}.$

I would then like to perform algebraic operations on, and, combine $y$ and $z$ such that one of the following happens:

We solve for $u,$ $t,$ or $v,$

We solve for $v - t$ or $t+v,$

We solve for $u-v$ or $u-t,$

We solve for $\frac{u}{v}$ or $\frac{u}{t},$

We solve for $tv$ or $t/v.$

In other words, if we can't isolate one of the $u,v,t$ variables, then perhaps we could at least isolate one of their sums or products.

Does there exist a function algebraic *strictly* in $y$ and $z$ such that one of the above is achieved? Or in other words, can we algebraically combine these two given expressions to isolate one of the variables or a sum or product of them? I don't know a theorem that says this is impossible, but it might be impossible, although I don't know why. The solutions I seek are all expressible over a field of the variables.

The goal is a solution strictly in terms of $y$ and $z,$

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. For problems like these Grobner basis might help.

Comment: Can use [Resultant](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/1.1643435555.png)

Comment: @DmitryEzhov I'm insure what's going on in your picture, but thanks for responding. Is this some type of polynomial division?

Comment: @StackQuest You have the sum and product $\,v+t=2u-y, vt=zu^2\,$, so $\,v,t\,$ are the roots of the quadratic $\,X^2-(2u-y)X+zu^2=0\,$ which gives $\,v,t\,$ in terms of $\,u\,$.

Comment: I'm unsure what's going on. You've introduced yet another new variable, so now the system is super-underdetermined? Or how does the introduction of this $X$ variable isolate $v$ and $t$? I understand the first two re-arrangements, but I don't understand this leap to a sudden new variable relating to a polynomial. Are you adding the two expressions together or what's going on? Why is $X$ not either $z$ or $y$?

Comment: @dxiv Sorry meant to "@" you.

Comment: @StackQuest If you know the sum $a+b=s$ and product $ab=p$ of two variables, then $a,b$ are the roots of the quadratic $X^2-sX+p=0$ which you can solve with the usual quadratic formula. This follows by elimination, or from Vieta's relations.

Comment: @dxiv That's interesting, but it's a brand new variable, this doesn't seem like it helps solve the system for either $u$ or a simple combination of $v$ and $t.$ What is this $X$?

Comment: Okay, I think you're saying you can isolate $v$ or $t$ in terms of $u,$ $y$ and $z.$ Well, that's nice except $u$ is inscribed within the solution, which you could have done by rearranging and solving the original equations without the introduction of this new quadratic. The caveat is that, since I can't isolate the variables without one of the other two, I was hoping isolate a simple sum or product of them would circumvent this such that the solution was only in terms of $y$ and $z.$

Comment: @StackQuest The quadratic gives you $\,v,t\,$ in terms of $\,u\,$. Not sure what more you are looking for, since the system is underdetermined and the solution set will necessarily depend on one free variable.